# add_action('the_content', 'my_plugin_content') is null

Tags: plugins, database, save-post

I am creating in personal plugin where I recover data from a personal table.
Con add_action('the_content', 'my_plugin_content'); posso far vedere il contenuto in una pagina.
I would like to save the content in wp_posts with add_filter ('save_post', 'my_plugin_content'), but the content is empty.

```
function my_plugin_content($content){
     $current_page = $wp->request;
     include_once(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'views/view.php');
     $obj = new Loader;
     $content.=$obj->controller($current_page);
     $my_post = array(); 
     $my_post['ID'] = $post->ID;
     $my_post['post_content']=$cont;
}
```

in another file I run the data recovery query that I refer to the file loader that loads the views

File loader

```php
public function view($view, array $dati){
      require(DIR_PLUGIN.'views/'.$view.'_v.php');
}
```

File view

```php
    <?php foreach($dati as $p){  echo '<p><strong>'.$p->NAME.'</strong></p>; }?>
```

Comment: You need to indent your code, a decent code editor will do this automatically, otherwise your code becomes very difficult for other people to read :( Have you removed parts of your filter?

Comment: I want to recover the contents of the view file with array variables php. The correct file View.
`public function view($view, array $dati){
      return require(DIR_PLUGIN.'views/'.$view.'_v.php');
}`

Comment: Ah so you want that as a string? That's a general PHP issue not a WP issue, use output buffers

Answer (score 0):

Filters **always** return something, they're not actions, they take something in, modify it, then return it, but your filter does neither.

As a result, PHP declares that it returned `null`, and the next filter along recieves `null` as the post content.

For example, this filter appends the word "Hey!" to the end of the content:

```php
add_filter( 'the_content', function ( $content ) {
    return $content . 'Hey!';
} );
```

So here are things you need to keep in mind:

- filters get called a lot, do not do heavy work in filters
- filters are for filtering, you take the first parameter, do things to it, then return it
- filters **always** return something
- do not `echo` stuff out on a filter, you're meant to `return` the full value with your modifications applied

Answer (score 0):

The content was null because the return statement was missing in some files.
I used the output buffers to retrieve the complete contentuno.. 
I decided to save the content in the main wordpress table.

```
function my_plugin_content($content){
     $current_page = $wp->request;
     include_once(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'views/view.php');
     $obj = new Loader;
     $content.=$obj->controller($current_page);
     $my_post = array(); 
     $my_post['ID'] = $post->ID;
     $my_post['post_content']=$content;
     wp_update_post($my_post);
}
```

The problem is that the content is added to the content of the existing post.
I want the content to be replaced.
What is the best practice?